# Texture.frame missing: (names of the texture)

Tags: json, phaser-framework

so I've been making a game, I have a map on this game but it shows me that error while checking the console. I'm using phaser and this is the code:

[Check the JSON code.](https://codeshare.io/gL1dvY)

Thats the map.json and here the png's im using:

[image: map-1.png]
[image: map-0.png]

[ERRORS HERE:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXwWD.jpg) https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXwWD.jpg

Hopefully someone can help me out fixing this, thank you so much!

Comment: Which error are you seeing? you didn't post the error message.

Comment: You can see the errors and assets here: https://imgur.com/a/QX6tTb6

Answer (score 0):

Well I would have to guess, that the filename of the `map-0` file ends with `jpg` or `jepg` or so *(it is not a png)*, but in the texture json, it is reference as such.

In the json containing the textures, you are pointing to `..."image": "map-0.png",...` and `..."image": "map-1.png",...` and since the file `map-0.png` is probably not found, none of those images can be displayed.

Just check that all files *(exact filename and extensions)* referenced in the json are in the folder, and it should work.

> **btw.:** some file mentioned in the console error message, are not in the json-file like for example: `igloo/item_small`, `igloo/item_large`, `igloo/card`, ...   are you missing a `json` file, or is the json the wrong version?

Comment: Nope, I uploaded the images as "map-0.png" and "map-1.png" to the VPS.

Comment: @IanBlack well as said I'm guessing. because the file byte header does contain the signature `PNG` (it contains`JFIF`), so it is not really a png (even if it might have that extension). and _a missing_ file could explain the console output **btw:** the error message complains about may missing images, and some are not in the json file. are you missing files? or did you just post an sample? the more accurate information you provide, the less I would have to guess to identify the problem.

Comment: No, I uploaded everything I have, thats the whole code and images that I uploaded to my VPS... Do you have Discord so I can provide you more stuff?

Comment: @IanBlack sorry I don't have discord. are you usin github maybe. Although I think, if you update your question with the relevant code, the Phaser Scene where you use the mulit-atlas (the `preload` and `create` functions  should suffice).

Comment: I don't have that, I only have the files I upload and share in this post.

Comment: @IanBlack if this the json is complete, the problem is, that you are referencing images, that are not definied in the the `json` (like the images: `igloo/item_small`, `igloo/item_large`, `igloo/card`, ... )

Comment: Then how can I fix this? I still don't understand, may you please give me an example? Sorry for being that annoying...  I'm new in this.

Comment: @IanBlack Well somewhere in your code you are adding sprites/images with the texture names('igloo/item_small', 'igloo/item_large', 'igloo/card', and may more in the console error). Solution, remove this, or add this files into the texture json. If that is not clear, I can't really help you sorry. (my be this offical example ca https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/loader/texture-atlas-multi/load-multi-texture-atlas)